# How should we be keeping track of secret doors?

Tags: dungeon

How are players keeping track of which doors a player has uncovered? Once you have discovered a door you do not need to roll again to find it. It seems like a lot to memorize or are we playing this game wrong?  Do all four get the knowledge of the door once uncovered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are playing the new WotC version, the rules state

> You might wish to keep track of the doors you found on a piece of
>   scrap paper

Now all you need is some way to easily reference a specific door.  You could try to describe the area it is in, like "Door to east-most level 4 room".

Of course, if you're playing the older "New Dungeon", it wouldn't really be a problem, because in that version you forgot about secret doors as soon as you moved away from them.

Comment: Ok thanks.  At least I know I am not doing something wrong

Comment: I think I need to write an app for this maybe